# Testing Google Play Store In-App-Purchases without creating signed APK

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, signing

I'm  testing In-App-Purchasing using the Google Play Billing API v3 with the [TrivialDrive](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html) IabHelper class. If I create a signed APK and install it on my test device, purchasing products works fine ([for the most part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30672893/google-play-store-reports-owned-in-app-purchase-items-as-not-owned-after-clear)), but if I simply run my app directly from Eclipse (i.e. unsigned) and try to trigger a purchase, the Play Store shows me this message instead of the purchase dialog:

```
Error

This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play.
Check the help center for more information.
```

And the IabHelper log outputs:

```
06-05 11:23:28.687: D/IabHelper(2727): Purchase canceled - Response: 5:Developer Error
```

It's quite painful to always have to generate an APK and upload it to the device to be allowed to test purchases. Is there a way to make this work with just running the app straight from Eclipse?

Comment: When you run your app from Eclipse, it's not unsigned - it's signed with a debug key. You could try replacing the debug key with your release key to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @adelphus That sounds like a very promising idea. Two quick questions if I may:  1. How would I do that? :)  2. Would I then have to enter my key-store passwords every time I run the app (if so, that's more pain than gain)?

Comment: 1. Google it :-) You basically have to replace the debug.keystore file in your home folder which Eclipse looks for to sign an App (don't forget to back up the original). 2. The debug.keystore file uses default passwords (one for keystore, one for the key) of "android" - once you create your own version of it (containing your own key of course), it should just work.

Comment: @adelphus That sounds good! Thanks! If you like, you can convert your comments to an answer, so I can accept it once I got it working! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using Android Studio and can easily create a signed apk and install directly on my device using a signingConfig for release buildType and installRelease task

Example build.gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
      release {
          storeFile <file>
          storePassword <password>
          keyAlias <alias>
          keyPassword <password>
      }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }
```

If you can load your app on Android Studio, I can help you with it.

Comment: Unfortunately all other platforms use Eclipse for coding (RoboVM, GWT, Blackberry, ...). So, I'm actually pretty annoyed by the fact that Google has decided to roll their own instead of focusing on fixing all the bugs in the SDK and libraries... Therefore, while I appreciate the help, I will try to avoid Android Studio for as long as I can... I'd rather focus my brain-cells on coding than learning another IDE... (I hope this doesn't sound like I'm upset at you or your answer. I really do appreciate the help. I'm only upset at Google in this respect.)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse signs Apps during development using a `debug.keystore` file stored in the `.android` folder in your home folder.

Replacing this file with a new Java keystore file containing your own signing key will allow you to run your App from Eclipse signed with your own key.

For Eclipse to accept the new keystore file, both the keystore and the key must be protected with the default password of "android" and the key must be named "androiddebugkey".